# Merge info from one list to another Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have two lists:

```
val generalInfo = List[GeneralInfo]
val countInfo = List[CountInfo]

case class GeneralInfo(id: String, source: String, languages: Array[String], var count: BigDecimal)
case class CountInfo(id: String, count: BigDecimal)
```

Every `GeneralInfo` object is initialized with `count = 0`;

I need to fill in the count variable in `GeneralInfo` object, with the count value from `CountInfo` object, when the id of them are the same. (not all the id's in `GeneralInfo` list are in `CountInfo` list)

I am quite new to Scala, is there any way to do it elegantly without a use of dictionary?

Comment: Why not using a dictionary? BTW a `var` in a case class is ver bad practice, you can use `copy` to modify the values by creating a new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that there's a one-to-one relation, you can go through every `CountInfo`, find the corresponding `GeneralInfo` object, and set the `count` for that `GeneralInfo`.

```
countInfo.foreach(c => generalInfo.find(_.id == c.id).map(_.count = c.count))
```

If one id can be shared by many `GeneralInfo` objects, use `filter` instead of `find`:

```
countInfo.foreach(c =>
  generalInfo.filter(_.id == c.id).foreach(_.count = c.count)
)
```

You can also do it the other way:

```
generalInfo.foreach(g => countInfo.find(_.id == g.id).map(c => g.count = c.count))
```

[Demo in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vI6arb2SSJqPWjCwiJ4CXw)

Comment: There is no one to one. in general info it is possible to have the same id, with a different source.